# How to scroll a line into the first visible row position in AceEditor

Tags: ace-editor

I'm using the find method `editor.find()` to find a specific search phrase in Ace Editor. Using the find method selects and scrolls the search phrase into view but it is not always at the first visible line.

Is there an option to scroll the selected row to the top of the editor?

Answer (score 3):

This works:

```
var searchResults = aceEditor.find("phrase");

if (searchResults) {
    aceEditor.scrollToLine(searchResults.start.row);
    aceEditor.clearSelection();
}
```